# ng-model can i check its own value?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have been playing with angular and I am currently in a pickle. I want to check to see if the ng-model value is greater then 0 to apply a different css style. Can this be done?

```
`<span ng-model="users2" ng-hide="!myVar" ng-class="{'test2': users2 > 0}"  style="font-size:28px; color:purple" >`
```

any help would be appreciated?
Thanks!

Comment: `ng-model` directive can be applied to form-controls only, like input, select or textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did everything right

[Look at this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nubicixale/edit?html,css,js,output)

Also look at the [ngClass Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for further examples.

If it doesn't work its probably another problem.

Edit:

I totally over seen that but as mentioned in the comments the [ngModel directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) binds an input, select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope.
So on a span it doesn't do anything and just isn't defined

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/pahilecewu/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: yeah, must be another problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want change css style for `span` on base of variable value you should use `ng-class`. You can use even `if-else` statement:

```
<div ng-class=" ... ? 'class-1' : ( ... ? 'class-2' : 'class-3')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline-styles are having a higher priority than css classes.

If you're adding `!important` to your class it should work as expected. But I would avoid to use inline styles. So only work with `ng-class`.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/tL24z8sr/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('mainController', MainController);
    
function MainController() {
 var vm = this;
    angular.extend(vm, {
     myVar: true,
        users2: 1
    });
}
```

```css
.test2 {
    color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
    <input ng-model="ctrl.users2"/>
    <span ng-hide="!ctrl.myVar" style="font-size:28px; color:purple" ng-class="{'test2': ctrl.users2 > 0}">
    some content
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-model works only on input box, text box, radio buttons, check boxes.
Since you have used ng-model on span, it wont update the model itself.

So $scope.users2 == undefined always